# I cant upload file large than 1 mb

Tags: php, ajax

i am using ajax and php to upload file i have this input

```
<input id="up_file" style="display:none;" accept=".gz" type="file" />
```

and this is javascript :-

```
$('#up_file').on("change",function() { 
 var file_data = $('#up_file').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
if (file_data){
$.ajax({
             url: 'upload_backup.php', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,        
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
             $("#message").append(data);
             $('#reload i').click();
            }



 });

}

 });
```

and this is php code

```
    <?php
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($ext == "gz"){
$file_name =str_ireplace('.sql.gz','',$_FILES['file']['name']);
$size =formatSizeUnits($_FILES['file']['size']);
$file_path ='backup_db/' . $file_name.'.sql.gz';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
    }else{
echo "Error Ext <br>";
    }

?>
```

i try this but not working

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M'); 

ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');

ini_set('max_input_time', 300); 

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: You should add more info. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: $_FILES is empty when send large than 1 mb @lucgenti

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **upload_max_filesize**, **post_max_size** and **max_input_time** settings can only be set in **php.ini**, **.htaccess**, **httpd.conf** and **.user.ini**. The **max_execution_time** can be set using ini_set.

See this link: [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php). It describes where each php configuration option can be set.

See also [Where a configuration setting may be set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). It describes the different places where php configuration options can be set